# Why does my login keep failing using fluent waits, tried explicit but that didn't work?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to login into my browser, I tried explicit waits i.e. expectedconditions.elementisvisible but this didn't work so I went down the route of fluentwaits.  At first fluent1 worked, then the second run fuentwait didn't work.  On the third run both don't work now

```
public void loginVT(IWebDriver driver)
        {

            _regRep = new UserRegRep(driver);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(_regRep.AppURL);

            DefaultWait<IWebDriver> fluentWait = new DefaultWait<IWebDriver>(driver);
            fluentWait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            fluentWait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000);
            fluentWait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
            IWebElement searchResult = fluentWait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("Email")));


            _regRep.Email.SendKeys("test@hotmail.com");
            String strFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("password.csv");
            _regRep.Password.SendKeys(strFile);
            _regRep.LogInButton.Click();

            //when the user icon is displayed, we have successfully logged in
             DefaultWait<IWebDriver> fluentWait1 = new DefaultWait<IWebDriver>(driver);
            fluentWait1.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            fluentWait1.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000);
            fluentWait1.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
            IWebElement searchResult1 = fluentWait1.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='User']")));

}
```

Comment: It seems to be complaining on the line where the searchResult and searchResult1 lines

Comment: What exception are you getting ?